# Add an existing xml element to a xml document

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

In this LINQ query I am creating a new XDocument for my own CD with track objects:

```
  var cdXml = new XDocument(new XElement("CD", new XAttribute("Artiest", c.Titel), new XAttribute("Naam", c.Naam),
            from t in c.tracks
            select new XElement("Tracks",
            new XElement("Track"),
            new XElement("Artiest", t.Artiest),
            new XElement("Titel", t.Titel),
            new XElement("Lengte", t.Lengte)
            )));
```

I am using an API from a music website and this is how I created the second XDocument from it:

```
    String xmlString;
    using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
    {
        xmlString = wc.DownloadString(@"http://link-to-method");
    }
    XDocument myXMLDoc = XDocument.Parse(xmlString);
```

After that I want to add the tracks from the myXMLDoc to my own cdXml document, I already added 3 tracks to the cdXml document and I only want to add the tracks from the myXMLDoc who aren't already in my cdXml document.

This is my query but it doesn't work:

```
            var query1 = from track in cdXml.Root.Elements("Tracks")
                        from track2 in myXMLDoc.Root.Element("album").Element("tracks").Elements("track")
                        where !track2.Element("name").Value.Contains(track.Element("Titel").Value)
                        select cdXml.Element("Tracks").Add(new XElement("Artiest", track2.Element("name").Value), 
new XElement("Titel", track2.Element("artist").Element("name").Value), 
new XElement("Lengte", track2.Element("duration").Value));
```

How do I add the existing elements from the myXMLDoc to my cdXml?

This is the xml file from the API call from 2 tracks:

```
<lfm status="ok">
    <album>
        <name>Awake</name>
        <artist>Dream Theater</artist>
        <mbid>e5544c68-43e9-4754-9239-b618454557f4</mbid>
        <url>https://www.last.fm/music/Dream+Theater/Awake</url>
        <image size="small">https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/34s/96e5ac5821bf4a138aec1b8f80f25a6f.png</image>
        <listeners>216679</listeners>
        <playcount>6046178</playcount>
        <tracks>
            <track rank="1">
                <name>6:00</name>
                <url>https://www.last.fm/music/Dream+Theater/_/6:00</url>
                <duration>331</duration>
                <streamable fulltrack="0">0</streamable>
                <artist>
                    <name>Dream Theater</name>
                    <mbid>28503ab7-8bf2-4666-a7bd-2644bfc7cb1d</mbid>
                    <url>https://www.last.fm/music/Dream+Theater</url>
                </artist>
            </track>
            <track rank="2">
                <name>Caught in a Web</name>
                <url>https://www.last.fm/music/Dream+Theater/_/Caught+in+a+Web</url>
                <duration>328</duration>
                <streamable fulltrack="0">0</streamable>
                <artist>
                    <name>Dream Theater</name>
                    <mbid>28503ab7-8bf2-4666-a7bd-2644bfc7cb1d</mbid>
                    <url>https://www.last.fm/music/Dream+Theater</url>
                </artist>
            </track>
    </album>
</lfm>
```

I finally found my own solution:

```
var query = from track in myXMLDoc.Root.Element("album").Element("tracks").Elements("track")
                        join track2 in cdXml.Root.Elements("Tracks") on track.Element("name").Value equals track2.Element("Titel").Value into joinedT
                        from track2 in joinedT.DefaultIfEmpty()
                        where track2 == null
                        select track;
```

Comment: *"it doesn't work:"* -- What do you expect that code to do, and what does it do instead?

Comment: I want to add the xml elements from myXMLDoc (artist, name, duration) to the cdXml document so it will add the: <name>Dream Theater</name> tags and content to it.

Comment: What did it do instead?

Answer (score 0):

First, write a query that returns the elements you want to add to the second document. Just that. Write a query that returns those. In the debugger, confirm that you're getting what you want to get.

Then, write a foreach loop which goes over those elements, and adds each one to whatever you want to add them to.

Your attempt at using `select` to add things is impossible. You can't do that. Linq isn't how you add things to collections. It's just for writing queries.

I think this might be what you were trying to do, I don't understand the `track`/`track2` thing in the first query.

```
var query1 = 
    from track in cdXml.Root.Elements("Tracks")
    from track2 in myXMLDoc.Root.Element("album").Element("tracks").Elements("track")
    where !track2.Element("name").Value.Contains(track.Element("Titel").Value)
    select track2;

query1 = query1.ToList();

//  Put a breakpoint HERE and examine query1 in the debugger to 
//  see what you got
;

foreach (var element in query1)
{
    cdXml.Element("Tracks").Add(
        new XElement("Artiest", element.Element("name").Value),
        new XElement("Titel", element.Element("artist").Element("name").Value),
        new XElement("Lengte", element.Element("duration").Value));
}
```

Comment: I now get a NullReferenceException

Comment: @meesie1 So find out what's null. You didn't provide any XML so I can't test this.

Comment: @meesie1 Did you use the debugger to find out what's in `query1`? Where are you getting the NullReferenceException? Where? What line?

Comment: <lfm status="ok">

<album>

<name>Awake</name>

<artist>Dream Theater</artist>

-<tracks>

</track>


-<track rank="2">

<name>Caught in a Web</name>

<url>https://www.last.fm/music/Dream+Theater/_/Caught+in+a+Web</url>

<duration>328</duration>

<streamable fulltrack="0">0</streamable>


-<artist>

<name>Dream Theater</name>

<mbid>28503ab7-8bf2-4666-a7bd-2644bfc7cb1d</mbid>

<url>https://www.last.fm/music/Dream+Theater</url>

</artist>

</track>

Comment: @meesie1 Please put that in your question. You cannot put it in comments. You cannot. Comments are too small. Not enough space in a comment. The XML is too big to fit.

Comment: I can't add xml it doesn't format on this page now I can't show you :(

Comment: @meesie1 Add it. Paste it in. Paste it into the question. Then select the XML text with the mouse and press Ctrl+K. Then submit. If you are unable to select the text or to locate the Ctrl and K keys, just submit it, and I'll fix it for you.

Comment: I added two tracks from the xml hope it is enough for you to see the structure.

Comment: @meesie1 Put it in your question, not in my answer. Do not put it in my answer. Please put it in your question. I rejected the edit. The XML needs to go in your question.

Comment: @meesie1 Thanks for adding it to your question. Unfortunately, what you added isn't valid XML. It's not possible for me to help you. Good luck.

Comment: The whole xml doc is about a 1000 lines you want me to print that?

Comment: @meesie1 When somebody wants XML to test something, they need valid XML. It could be a valid subset of the whole file: Maybe just include one album with three tracks instead of twenty albums. However, the essential structure must be intact. **It must parse** and must accurately represent what you are parsing. They cannot be expected to guess what is missing. Guessing is a complete waste of everybody's time.

Comment: @meesie1 I won't try to help you any more because you fight me every step of the way. You ignore half of my questions and you refuse to answer the others properly. I don't enjoy that game. You'll have to find somebody else to play it with.

Comment: I added all the end tags of the xml for 2 tracks now you must be able to see properly how the structure looks like, sorry about the indentation I am new to stack. I know with indentation the xml is better to see.

Comment: First you need to get your first Linq query right. Start at the simplest possible thing: `from track in cdXml.Root.Elements("Tracks")
                    select track;` Figure out why that doesn't work (free hint: It doesn't work). Once you get that working, move on to the next step. One step at a time. Use the watch window in the debugger to see what is in the collections. Set breakpoints and use the watch window to see what is in every variable you are dealing with. Once you can get the tracks, figure out how to get the tracks from `myXMLDoc`.

Comment: DO NOT TRY to do everything in one giant Linq statement. Break it into small pieces. In fact, you probably should use Linq as little as possible. It's making things much harder for you, and this exercise is pushing your limits very hard to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution :

```
            XElement tracks =  cdXml.Root.Element("Tracks");

            List<XElement> query1 = myXMLDoc.Root.Element("album").Element("tracks").Elements("track")
                .Where(track2 => track2.Element("name").Value.Contains(track.Element("Titel").Value)).ToList();

            foreach (XElement q1 in query1)
            {
                tracks.Add(new XElement("Artiest", q1.Element("name").Value),
                         new XElement("Titel", q1.Element("artist").Element("name").Value),
                         new XElement("Lengte", q1.Element("duration").Value));
            }
```